# $f^2g$ integrable then $fg$ integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, fix measurable functions $f,g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^2g$ is integrable.

Is also $fg$ integrable?

Comment: Choose $X = [0,1]$, $g=1/x^{3/2}$, $f=x^{1/2}$.

Comment: @user251257 What's the probability measure?

Comment: $\mu(\mathbb N) = 1$.So, you weight $n$ by $2^{-n}$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: oh i oversaw that $P(\Omega)=1$, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Take my example in the comments: $X = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, $g(x) = \frac 1 {x^{3/2}}$ and $f(x) = x^{1/2}$.